# How to find position of object on a parabola?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, quadratics, conic-sections

I'm making a computer game, where an object flies along a parabola curve. This object is 'thrown' by a 'robot' towards another robot.

I know the vertex of the parabola, and also it's two intersections with the x axis.

I also now the object's x position.

**I need a way to find the object's y position on the parabola.**

I'm not great in math, so I'd like the method to do this be as simple as possible. Please try to explain it in a way I'll be able to understand.

My parabola: [image]

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you know the $x$ values for which the parabola intersects $y=0$, you can write $y=(x-a)(x-b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are these two $x$ values.

Comment: @Lost Thanks for trying to help, but I don't see how this can work. This formula doesn't involve the vertex of the parabola. I need to find an actual point on the parabola, knowing it's x but needing to find it's y.

Comment: If it is simple finding the point y for a given x, you use the value x and plug into the equation @lost provided. But the parabola comes from the equation of motion where height (y) and x are parameterised with time? I may be assuming too much here?

Comment: @Chinny84 I didn't understand too much of what you wrote :/ But I think that Lost's formula won't work because it doesn't involve the vertex of the parabola. As I said in my question, I need to find the position of an object on the parabola. I have the object's x co-ordinate, and I have the parabola's vertex, and two intersects with the x axis. Now, I need to find the object's y co-ordinate. Is this possible?

Comment: @user3150201 I have tried answering your question. Not completely show if this is what you wanted. If it is not, then I will remove :).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, assuming that $y = ax^{2} + bx + c$:
The vertex is given by 
$$
y' = 0 = 2ax + b \implies x_{vertex} = -\frac{b}{2a}.
$$
Now we also have the intercepts of the x axis given by the quadratic formula,
$$
x = \frac{-b}{2a}\pm\frac{\sqrt{b^{2}-4ac}}{2a}.
$$
Now does y = x = 0? since that will give c. So from knowing the vertex value and the roots and the intercept of y at x = 0 we can define any point on y in terms of x. Alternatively if we set robot 1 to have x-cord of (x,y)=(0,0) then c = 0. From here you can compute what a, and b are from the vertex value and the points that the robots are placed.

More explicitly:
$$
\mathrm{vertex} = -\frac{b}{2a}\\
\mathrm{robot\,1\,position} = \frac{-b}{2a} - \frac{\sqrt{b^{2}-4ac}}{2a}\\
\mathrm{robot\,2\, position} = \frac{-b}{2a} + \frac{\sqrt{b^{2}-4ac}}{2a}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You are given the coordinate of the vertex $(h,k)$ and two distinct real roots, which by symmetry can be written as $h\pm r$  for some $r>0.$

Then the equation for the parabola is

$$y=-\frac{k}{r^2}(x-h)^2+k.$$

---

Another way to express this:

You are given distinct real roots $r_1,r_2$ and coordinate of vertex $\left(\frac{r_1+r_2}{2},k\right).$

Then the equation for the parabola is

$$y=-\frac{4k}{(r_1-r_2)^2}(x-r_1)(x-r_2).$$